# Write a comma in a system of equations

Tags: equations, overleaf

I am writing the following system of equations:

```
\[
\spalignsys{
$s^{-1}F(\lambda,s(\varphi_0+y)) \hspace{1cm} s\not = 0$;
$D_uF(\lambda,0)(\varphi_0+y) \hspace{1cm} s = 0$
}
\]
```

But the commas do not appear.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You get several error messages from that code. After removing all `$` characters, the output is

[image]

which isn't what's expected, is it?

You're using the wrong tool.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cases}
s^{-1}F(\lambda,s(\varphi_0+y)) & s \not= 0 \\
D_uF(\lambda,0)(\varphi_0+y)    & s = 0
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]